# Meteor message format server side translation

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm doing server side validation with [message format](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-messageformat) on a meteor app and I would like to get error messages back to client, localized in the user language (previously set in the client with mfPkg.setLocale("userLanguage")). How can I accomplish this task in the correct way?
On server side the messages are not localized and I'm not sure how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mf()` function on the server too. Just specify the locale as fourth parameter:

```
var key = 'helloname';
var params = { name: "Jeff" };
var message = "Hello {name}!";
var locale = 'da';
var translatedMessage = mf(key, params, message, locale);
```

Now obviously you have to know the visitor's locale for this to work. You can't access the client-side `Session` global. In my case I've synced the locale to `Meteor.user().profile.locale` so I can read it from there for logged-in users.

Do the translation on the client if you can. If you have messageformat loaded on the client, just pass the key and let the client translate the error. (I know this is not always possible.)